# IE10 : Two divs are side by side on hover

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10

I have a `div` and a `hover_div` on it. On that `hover_div` , I have two `divs` which I want them to be up and down not side by side. It works fine in **IE11** but not in **IE10**.

How can I solve it to look the same in **IE10**.

```css
.main_div{
  width:160px;
  height:160px;
  border:thin black solid;
  padding:5px;
  position:relative;
  
  /* Firefox */
  display:-moz-box;
  -moz-box-orient:horizontal;
  -moz-box-pack:center;
  -moz-box-align:center;

/* Safari and Chrome */
  display:-webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
  -webkit-box-pack:center;
  -webkit-box-align:center;

/* W3C */
  display:box;
  box-orient:horizontal;
  box-pack:center;
  box-align:center;

  /* IE10 -Doesn't work yet! */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -ms-box-orient:horizontal;

}

.main_div .hover_div{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: none;
  
}

.main_div .hover_div .upload_btn{
background: white;
            padding: 3px 20px;
            color: #58666e;
            margin: 8px 0;
            
}

.main_div:hover .hover_div{
 /* Firefox */
  display:-moz-box;
  -moz-box-orient:horizontal;
  -moz-box-pack:center;
  -moz-box-align:center;

/* Safari and Chrome */
  display:-webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
  -webkit-box-pack:center;
  -webkit-box-align:center;

/* W3C */
  display:box;
  box-orient:horizontal;
  box-pack:center;
  box-align:center;

  /* IE10 -Doesn't work yet! */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -ms-box-orient:horizontal;

}
```

```html
<div class="main_div">
     <div class="hover_div">
         <div class="upload_btn cursor_pointer">
              <span>xyz</span>
         </div>
         <div class="upload_btn">
              <span>abc</span>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I have used `box-orient` property value from `horizontal` to `vertical`.

but it is not working in **IE10**

Any help would be same.

Thank You.

Comment: Tried your code in this fiddle => https://jsfiddle.net/r5r44rL1/1/ , I could see same output in Chrome and IE10. Am I missing something?

Comment: I want two divs next and under each other.

Comment: What is the need of using `box-orient` property?

Comment: i want 2 div to be under next to each other , that's why I have used it